# A = {1, 2, 3, ... , 10}. How many pairs of subsets of A like (X, Y) are there such that...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A = {1, 2, 3, ... , 10}. How many pairs of subsets of A like (X, Y)
>   are there such that:
>
> (a) X = A and |Y| = 3?
>
> (b) $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $X \cup Y = A$?
>
> (c) $|X \cap Y| = 2$ and $X \cup Y = A$?
>
> (d) $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $|X \cup Y| = 8$?

So far what I have is as follows:

When A = {1, 2, 3, ... , 10}, the pair of subsets is $2^{10} $

(a) When |Y| = 3, then there are $2^3 = 8$ pairs of subsets

(b) When $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ there are $2^0 = 1$ pair

When $X \cup Y = A$? there are $2^{10} = 1024$ pairs

(c) When $|X \cap Y| = 2$ there are $2^2 = 4$ pairs

(d) When $|X \cup Y| = 8$ there are $2^8 = 256$ pairs

I have a feeling this is way off the mark and not what the question is asking, so if anyone could lead me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you learn $C_k^n$ or $n \choose k$ or picking $k$ distinct objects from $n$ distinct objects?

Answer (score 1):

a) There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to choose $Y$. Since $X$ is determined, that gives a total of $\binom{10}{3}$ ordered pairs $(X,Y)$.

b) $X$ can be any of the $2^{10}$ subsets of $A$, and for any $X$, there only one possibility for $Y$, namely $A\setminus X$. So the number of ordered pairs is $2^{10}$.

c) There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to choose the two elements $X$ and $Y$ have in common. For any such choice, the rest of $X$ can be any subset of the $8$ remaining elements of $A$, and then $Y$ gets what's left over, for a total of $\binom{10}{2}2^8$.

d) It's your turn, think about Problem c). I can help if there is difficulty.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm presuming (d) is quite similar to (b) in that the intersection of X and Y is empty so it's 2^0, and the cardinality of the union of X and Y is 8, so 2^8 = 256 pairs of subsets?

Comment: You are welcome. There are two ways to do it. (i) Think of complements. Then it should become clear that the answer is the same as the one for c). (ii) Work as in c). There are $\binom{10}{8}$ ways to choose the lucky eight who will be split between $X$ and $Y$, and then there are $2^8$ ways to do the splitting, for a total of $\binom{10}{8}2^8$.